# Results of displayLanguage and contentLanguage for Excel

Tags: office-js

I am new to Office JS. By using the Script Lab Add-In in Excel 2016, I retrieved the display and content languages of my current installation of Excel 2016. I used the code below:

```html
$("#run").click(run);

async function run() {
    try {
        await Excel.run(async (context) => {

            console.log("DL=" + Office.context.displayLanguage);
            console.log("CL=" + Office.context.contentLanguage);

            await context.sync();
        });
    }
    catch (error) {
        OfficeHelpers.Utilities.log(error);
    }
}
```

I have 3 language packs installed for Office: German, English and French. When running the code, I noticed that both `displayLanguage` and `contentLanguage` are resulting the same value, independently from what language is set as *default* editing language in the Office Language Settings tool.

Example: I set the UI language to German and English as default for the Editing Language. Both properties return `de_DE`. If I set English as UI language and French as default editing language, I get `en_US` for both properties.

So, my question is, am I doing something wrong or misunderstanding the doc on the Office DevCenter at [Context.contentLanguage property](https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/shared/office.context.contentlanguage) or is there something wrong with the result?

Thanks in advance.

Best,
Mourad

Comment: Just to clarify, are you saying displayLanguage is always returning the correct value? Just want to make sure we're on the same page, displayLanguage is correct but contentLanguage is always returning the same value as displayLanguage.

Comment: Hello Marc, yes, displayLanguage returns the correct value of the active UI language. And yes, for me, contentLanguage then always returns the same value as displayLanguage.

Comment: So, I think, I have understood the difference and I would like to share this. In Excel-Online, it is for example possible to have the User Interface in English and the formulas in German. Then, `displayLanguage` returns en_us and `contentLanguage` returns de_de. This situation can never happen in the locally installed Excel App. So, they both return the same.